# How to test data points in Matlab's contour function

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

So I have a 2 (or 3) dimensional contour plot with a contour line going along Z = 100. Given a data point I would like to test which side of the contour line that data point is on.

Any recommendations on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a logical condition? `p>100` will return true (or 1) if inside etc ...

Comment: Please clearify your question. What you mean with "test"? Plot it or just a logical answer (0,1) ?